# Unable to Set Chrome as Default Web Browser

Tags: windows, browser, regedit

## Problem:

I recently installed Avast Secure Browser on my Windows system and have encountered an issue with setting Google Chrome as my default web browser. It seems that a key in the Regedit editor has been modified during the Avast installation, causing Chrome to be excluded from the available default browser options.

Is anyone familiar with a similar situation where installing Avast Secure Browser has interfered with the ability to set Chrome as the default browser? I suspect that a registry key modification by Avast is causing this problem.

## Here are the details of the issue I'm facing:

- After installing Avast Secure Browser, I noticed that Chrome is no longer visible as an option in the "Default Apps" settings.
- Only Edge is displayed correctly, but with no icon.
- I suspect that a registry key has been modified by Avast during the installation process, causing this unexpected behavior.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or steps to resolve this issue and restore Chrome as my default browser. Specifically, I'm seeking assistance on:

- Identifying the registry key(s) that Avast Secure Browser might have modified, preventing Chrome from being recognized as a default browser.
- Guidance on how to modify the registry key(s) correctly to reinstate Chrome as the default browser.
- Any alternative solutions or workarounds to resolve this issue.

Please note that I'm using Windows 10 Pro and have administrative privileges on my system. Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise!

I have already search for all "avast" key in the regedit and deleted them. But nothing has seems to happened

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Please delete this** and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you having local active directory domain then perhaps apply via GPO. If you install the ADMX templates for Google Chrome, you can use the [group policy setting](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en) to force it.

Meanwhile if it’s standalone PC then perhaps try this:

1. Press `Windows + S` -> type `cmd` -> right click on `Command Prompt` -> choose `Run as administrator`.
2. Type or copy & paste this command: `explorer.exe shell:::{17cd9488-1228-4b2f-88ce-4298e93e0966} -Microsoft.DefaultPrograms\pageDefaultProgram`.
3. Hit Enter and wait for the command to finish.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the solution you are looking for, but you can open Chrome go to Chrome settings and in search settings type"default browser", you can make Chrome your default browser that way too.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]